# cannot import name commit_on_success , Mockups en django 1.9

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

He instalado Mockups en django 1.9, inicialmente me mando el error: ImportError for import_module y lo he solucionado con: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32761566/django-1-9-importerror-for-import-module
ahora me sale otro error de importacion:

```
File "/home/alejandro/django190/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockups/management/commands/mockups.py", line 30, in <module>
from django.db.transaction import commit_on_success ImportError: cannot import name commit_on_success
```

como corregir ello?, gracias

Comment: ese error me sale cuando intengo  insertar registros de prueba, digamos: python manage.py mockups apps.personal.Asistencia:500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo he solucionado, guiándome con este post 
https://github.com/sorl/django-mockups/pull/22/commits/73057042c752391652ef7a5d0a5440693d5430b3

reemplazar @commit_on_success por @atomic en linea 120 aprox y mas abajo mas o menos por la linea 122 reemplazar from django.db.models import get_model por:

```
 try:
        from django.apps import apps
        get_model = apps.get_model
    except ImportError:
        # Support django < 1.8
        from django.db.models import get_model
```

mis importaciones quedo asi

```
from importlib import import_module
from django.db.transaction import atomic
```

por si caso el archivo en mi caso esta dentro del virtualenv y mockups.py se en el directoriio

```
django190/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockups/management/commands/mockups.py
```

Answer (score 1):

`commit_on_success` fue eliminado y reemplazado con `atomic` en 1.6 (o 1.7/8 no me recuerdo).

Tu ejemplo indica que `mockups.py` no esta al dia. En `mockups.py` intenta a cambiar `from django.db.transaction import commit_on_success` a `from django.db.transaction import atomic`.

Comment: Ahora me arroja este error, al parecer no esta importando lo que tiene que ver con commit_on_success.

File "/home/alejandro/django190/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockups/management/commands/mockups.py", line 39, in <module>
    class Command(BaseCommand):
  File "/home/alejandro/django190/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mockups/management/commands/mockups.py", line 119, in Command
    @commit_on_success
NameError: name 'commit_on_success' is not defined

Comment: O Quizá es muy antiguo el paquete, quizá habrá otra herramienta para poder insertar registros de prueba en bloque... para django 1.9?

Comment: Gracias @Will Robertson me ayudó mucho tu respuesta